# JQuery issues after using load to load external html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below to load html into my page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('#loadingArea').load('includes/template1.html');

});
```

It works great but for some reason when I use any query to target any divs belonging to the loaded html file it won't work for example:

template1.html contains:

Button Inside the Template

If I try to use:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){

    alert('Something');        

});
```

It will not work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [delegate the events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Delegate the event by attaching to the nearest static object:

```
$("#loadingArea").on("click", "#mybutton", function(){
    alert('Something');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

learn about [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) see:

```
$("body").on('click','#mybutton',function(){

    alert('Something');        

});
```